# Deleting Python 3.6 from Ubuntu 18.4

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed Python 3.8 and then deleted python 3.6. But then suddenly my installed apps started to disappear. And within a minute all apps were removed. Then I rebooted and it booted into CUI.

Comment: You are stating a fact. Not a problem. What is it you want to achieve? When you uninstalled python 3.6 did you get a notice about what is was going to uninstall. Like ...  a very very very long list of applications? If you want a desktop back, I would assume that is the idea, reinstall it from command line.

Comment: I used *sudo apt-get purge python3.6* this command. Nothing prompted and everything went on its own.

Comment: Since you have apparently purged an important part of your system, the easiest way to recover is a clean-install of Ubuntu. Folks with experience can reconstruct the system using dpkg (you broke apt), but it's tedious and slow. Remember to back up your data before reinstalling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reinstalling Ubuntu is probably the easiest way, it's worth pointing out that it's possible to recover without reinstalling everything.

To do this, manually download the `python3.6` package (and its dependencies), and manually install them using `dpkg` (bypassing APT, which requires Python). Once that's installed, apt should work again, and so `apt install ubuntu-desktop` will restore your system. (If `apt` still doesn't work, you might also need to download and install any missing dependencies.)

In the future, if you need to reinstall a package, instead use

```
sudo apt get install --reinstall python3.6
```

which will reinstall the package without having to remove the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same mistake and fixed by using the below commands

sudo apt install xorg

sudo apt apt install ubuntu-desktop